# bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected() issue

Tags: scripting, import

I try to import an obj file and make a rendered image, by a python script.
How to center the view to the mesh?

I've tried `bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected()` but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "J:\Programmi\blender-2.75a-windows32\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", l
ine 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.action.view_selected.poll() failed, context is in
correct
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't have a reference to a specific window, you can iterate over all screen areas, and call the operator on all `VIEW_3D` area types.

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(ctx)            # points view
        # bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected(ctx)   # points camera
```

I think the topic and resolutions to *context is incorrect* [have been covered exhaustively](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) .

If you use `camera_to_view_selected(ctx)` you can break the loop early if you only have one camera to point, else it will point the camera at the same thing for every 3dview opened.

Comment: Thanks @zeffii, no exception now, but the command seems not to work. Here a rendered output example: http://156.54.99.175/3d/preview.jpg I want to call **Numpad Period** from script.

Comment: I see.. what you're doing there is using a Camera to render. This (although seemingly related) has nothing to do with `view32.view_selected()` -- which only controls the viewing angle of the viewport, in much the same way as you would use your mouse to position the view so you could see stuff better.  ---- That being said you can allign the active camera to the view using another command.`bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()
`

Comment: i'll update my answer so this isn't lost

Comment: Thanks again @zeffii ! Now I get: http://156.54.99.175/3d/preview2.jpg how about light? How to get better light in scene? I have to act on the context?

Comment: you should ask a separate question about lights.. and scripting of light positions.